# Linear gradient with css variable and hsla

Tags: html, css

I have a css variable:

```
:root{
 --red: hsl(0, 100%, 74%);
}
```

And then this does not work:

```
.page-wrapper{
  background-image: linear-gradient(hsla(var(--red),.6), hsla(var(--red),.6)), url(./images/bg-intro-desktop.png);
}               /**** This does not work for some reason****/
```

If i replace `var(--red)` with values it works:

```
.page-wrapper{
  background-image: linear-gradient(hsla(0, 100%, 74%,.6), hsla(0, 100%, 74%,.6)), url(./images/bg-intro-desktop.png);
}   /**** This works well ****/
```

I was not able to find an answer to this issue, thanks for your help!

Comment: try `--red: 0, 100%, 74%;`

Comment: @TemaniAfif oh it works, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Mind the syntax. (see https://codepen.io/baadaa/pen/XWJwXaZ )

```css
// DO THIS
:root {
  --red: 0, 100%, 74%;
}
```